# Declare self-type of a child trait in a parent trait in scala

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits, self-type

I have some scala traits with same self-type declared as following.

```
trait BookDbModule {
  self: DbConfig => // Abstract this to a parent trait
  /* ... */
}

trait AuthorDbModule {
  self: DbConfig => // Abstract this to a parent trait
  /* ... */
}
```

I am trying to abstract the self-type declaration to a parent trait such that each of these traits does not have to define self-type. I tried the following.

```
trait DbModule {
  self: DbConfig =>
  // Some common DbModule methods
}

// !!! Illegal Inheritance, self-type BookDbModule does not conform to DbConfig
trait BookDbModule extends DbModule {
  // What needs to be used instead of extends?
  /* ... */
}

// !!! Illegal Inheritance, self-type AuthorDbModule does not conform to DbConfig
trait AuthorDbModule extends DbModule {
  // What needs to be used instead of extends?
  /* ... */
}
```

The error messages `Illegal Inheritance` makes sense to me as `BookDbModule` does not extend `DbConfig`.

Is there any way in Scala to enforce self-type of children traits in a parent trait?

**Update:**
It seems like the question is little bit confusing.

What I want to achieve is, I want to omit necessity to set self-type for `BookDbModule` and `AuthorDbModule` by extending (or any other scala feature) the parent trait `DbModule` while has the self-type `DbConfig`.

So, basically, I am looking for a way to make children traits (`BookDbModule` and `AuthorDbModule`) be extended by only those classes with `DbConfig` by declaring self-type in parent `DbModule` but not in those children traits.

```
// This works but is there any way to omit necessity to write
// self: DbConfig =>
trait AuthorDbModule extends DbModule {
  self: DbConfig =>
  /* ... */
}
```

Please let me know if it is still confusing.

Thank You!

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to achieve. The messages (to me, at least) _do_ say that they're "enforcing self-type of traits".

Comment: Hi @RobStarling, I have updated my question. Please take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the update, makes it more clear

Comment: ah! got it. sorry, but i think the answer is "no".

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

```
scala> trait DbConfig { def f = 123 }
defined trait DbConfig
```

`DbModule` that requires `DbConfig` implementation:

```
scala> trait DbModule { self: DbConfig => }
defined trait DbModule
```

`BookDbModule` is of type `DbModule`, still requires `DbConfig` implementation:

```
scala> trait BookDbModule extends DbModule { self: DbConfig => }
defined trait BookDbModule
scala> new BookDbModule with DbConfig {}.f
res0: Int = 123
```

`BookDbModule` is of type `BookDbModule`, requires `DbConfig` implementation directly:

```
scala> trait BookDbModule { self: DbConfig => }
defined trait BookDbModule
scala> new BookDbModule with DbConfig {}.f
res1: Int = 123
```

`BookDbModule` is of type `BookDbModule`, requires `DbModule` implementation, which in turn requires `DbConfig` implementation:

```
scala> trait BookDbModule { self: DbModule => }
defined trait BookDbModule

scala> new BookDbModule with DbConfig {}.f
<console>:14: error: illegal inheritance;
 self-type BookDbModule with DbConfig does not conform to BookDbModule's selftype BookDbModule with DbModule
       new BookDbModule with DbConfig {}.f
           ^

scala> new BookDbModule with DbConfig with DbModule {}.f
res3: Int = 123
```

You can also use inheritance:

```
trait BookDbModule extends DbModule with DbConfig
scala> new BookDbModule with DbConfig {}.f
res4: Int = 123
```

However *you can't inherit a self type annotation somehow*, so you can either resort to inheritance, or annotate with self types explicitly. Note that this simplification is also possible:

```
scala> trait DbConfig { def f = 123 }
defined trait DbConfig

scala> trait DbModule { self: DbConfig => }
defined trait DbModule

scala> trait DbModuleService extends DbModule with DbConfig
defined trait DbModuleService
```

Closest to what you are looking for, but has to use intermediate trait `DbModuleService` that is "complete":

```
scala> trait BookDbModule extends DbModuleService
defined trait BookDbModule

scala> new BookDbModule {}.f
res0: Int = 123
```

Or:

```
scala> trait DbConfig { def f = 123 }
defined trait DbConfig

scala> trait DbModule { self: DbConfig => }
defined trait DbModule

scala> trait DbModuleService extends DbModule with DbConfig
defined trait DbModuleService

scala> trait BookDbModule { self: DbModuleService => }
defined trait BookDbModule

scala> new BookDbModule with DbModuleService {}.f
res0: Int = 123
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It seems like the question was a bit confusing (updated). The error makes sense. What I wanted to do was omit the necessity to write `self: DbConfig =>` after `extends DbModule`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. It is not possible. In fact what you say is against the purpose of self typing.

```
trait DbModule {
  self: DbConfig =>
}

trait BookDbModule extends DbModule {
}
```

In your example (summarized here), `DbModule` says my children must somehow provide the functionality defined in `DbConfig`. But trait `BookDbModule` cannot show that unless it either extends `DbConfig` or explicitly self type it. And that is against what you wanted...